# Azure VPN に繋いでいる mac と ubuntu の間で ping が通らない

Tags: macos, ubuntu, azure, vpn, iptables

azure vpn gateway を作成して、mac と ubuntu 18.04 は p2s 接続することができました。
しかし、お互いのマシンは ping を送信しても packat が届きません。
どうしたら届くようになるのでしょうか？

ルートフォワードの設定はいるのでしょうか？

■ azure vnet subnet

- FrontEnd

  - 10.1.0.0/24
- GatewaySubnet

  - 10.1.255.0/27
- address space

  - 10.0.0.0/16
  - 10.1.0.0/16

■ azure vnet gateway

- address pool

  - 172.16.201.0/24
- tunnel type

  - openVPN

■ mac

- wifi ssid

  - A
- private ip address network interface

  - eth0

    - 10.2.59.83
  - utun3（vpn）

    - inet 172.16.201.4 --> 172.16.201.4
- netstat -rn

```
    172.16/24          utun3              USc             utun3
    172.16.201/24      link#17            UCS             utun3
    172.16.201.4       172.16.201.4       UH              utun3
    192.168.0/23       utun3              USc             utun3
```

■ ubuntu 18.04

- wifi ssid

  - B
- private ip address network interface

  - wlan0

    - 192.168.100.208
  - tun0（vpn）

    - 172.16.201.3/24
- route

```
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    20600  0        0 wlan0
    default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    32766  0        0 l4tbr0
    10.0.0.0        _gateway        255.255.0.0     UG    50     0        0 tun0
    10.1.0.0        _gateway        255.255.0.0     UG    50     0        0 tun0
    link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 l4tbr0
    172.16.201.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     50     0        0 tun0
    172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
    192.168.55.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 l4tbr0
    192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
```

Comment: Mac や Ubuntu 自身は ping を受け付ける状態ですか？ / VPN 接続中にクライアント同士で ping が必要なのはなぜでしょうか？

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。はい。VPN切断中は同じネットワーク内にいる状態です。その時は普通にping がお互い通ります。vpn接続中は単純にpingで疎通確認をしておきたいと思いました。